# Load data into ListFragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-listfragment

I would like to load data from network into fragments. Inside the `Activity` I have a `ViewPager` and I am using a `FragmentPagerAdapter` to provide fragments to it. The problem is:

How can I detect from activity, that ALL fragments from ViewPager are created and ready to show data. How can I inform fragments, that there is a data inside activity, that should be shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I detect from activity, that ALL fragments from ViewPager are
>   created and ready to show data.

This sounds a bit strange to ask. You `Activity` doesn't need to know when all of the `ViewPager` fragments are initialized(as only one will actually be seen by the user(plus one on each side will be available if you don't mess with `setOffScreenPageLimit()`), it doesn't make sense to update the rest).

> How can I inform fragments, that there is a data inside activity, that
>   should be shown?

You fragments could register themselves as listeners for an `Activity` data load event. The `Activity` will do it's job of getting the data and then call the update method on all of the registered fragments(which should be stored in `WeakReferences` to avoid holding on to them  when we shouldn't). The main problem is you'll risk trying to update items

Another hacky approach is to use something like from the `Activity`:

```
// get the current fragment(add/subtract one for the available fragments on each side of the curently visible 
Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.ViewPagerId + ":" + mViewPager.getCurrentItem()); one.)
f.update();
```

The rest of the fragments will check for new data being available when they get recreated.